# Как удалить дочерние записи без родителей в mySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, relation

Есть таблица. `id | parent_id.`

У некоторых `parent_id` нет родителя. 
Как удалить сирот?

К примеру, есть запись с `parent_id = 10`, а её родителя с `id = 10` - нет.
Как я понимаю, что-то вроде

```
DELETE FROM table t LEFT JOIN table t1 ON t.id = t1.parent_id WHERE t.id IS NULL
```

Comment: parent_id = NULL?

Comment: А что значит "нет родителя". parent_id=NULL или он не NULL, но ссылается на несуществующую запись ?

Comment: Нет записи с таким id, а с parent_id - есть

Comment: Забавный факт: после того, как вы удалите эти записи-сироты, другие записи могут стать сиротами. Так можно рекурсивно повторять удаления, пока не останутся только записи с `parent_id = NULL`.

Answer (score 4):

```
delete from test3
 where id in(
        select id from (
          select id
            from test3 A
           where not exists(select 1 from test3 B where B.id=A.parent_id)
          ) as X
       )
    and parent_id is not NULL
```

Лишняя вложенность запроса и алиас (X) необходима так как MySQL иначе не позволяет обращаться к той же таблице из которой происходит удаление.

**UPD:** Я погорячился в комментариях по поводу left join, вариант с ним рабочий и выглядит явно короче:

```
delete A.*
  from test3 A
  left join test3 B
    on B.id=A.parent_id
 where B.id is NULL and A.parent_id is not NULL
```

Скорость работы стоит сравнить

Comment: Такой запрос, наверное, положит мне сервер =)) Около 200 000 записей. Как думаете?

Comment: @ОлегГригорьев А ваш left join произведет то же самое, что и not exists. Попробуйте для начала скорость работы самого подзапроса получающего список.

Comment: Разве эти запросы не удалят также записи с `parent_id = NULL`?

Comment: @Mike, большое спасибо за ответ. Работает, но не хватает parent_id <> NULL. А то удалятся еще и родители верхнего уровня, у которых, конечно, нет родителей. А JOIN что-то не работает. Либо же вся загвоздка в A.*, проверим...

Answer (score -1):

```
DELETE FROM myTable WHERE parent_id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM parents);
```

Comment: Записи в одной таблице

Comment: в чем проблема? используйте одну таблицу в запросе

Comment: Не работает. MySQL иначе не позволяет обращаться к той же таблице из которой происходит удаление, как сказал @Mike в своём ответе. Ну и документация, думаю, тоже самое сказала.

Comment: Да и в принципе использование NOT IN ( большое количество записей) - плохая практика. Не спорю, есть случаи, когда без этого не обойтись. Но здесь же можно по-другому.