# Как грамотно объединить два sql запроса?

Tags: sql

Я не слишком хорош в SQL и пытаюсь сделать нужный мне запрос, каким-то обрзаом объеденив два разных запроса:

1. Поиск в справочнике значения которое ввел пользователь (arg1):

   ```
   select ShortWord from ShortWords where ShortWord like 'arg1'
   ```
2. Поиск в пользовательской таблице такого же значения (arg1):

   ```
   select WORDCOLLECT from CollectWords where WORDCOLLECT like 'arg1';
   ```

Результат запроса должен вывести все значения из справочника, за исключением тех, которые найдены в пользовательской таблице.

Как это лучше реализовать? Пытался через JOIM'ы, но скорей всего я что-то делаю не так.

Comment: left join и проверка на NULL в части where. примерно как тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/558500/194569 (см. вторую часть) только select, а не delete ;)

Comment: Ну или `not in` если записей на много

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если привязка наборов данных конкретно по словам, может так?:

```
SELECT
  s.ShortWord
FROM ShortWords s
WHERE
  s.ShortWord LIKE 'arg1'
  AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM CollectionWords c
    WHERE
      c.WORDCOLLECT = s.ShortWord
      AND c.WORDCOLLECT LIKE 'args1'
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

если данные в двух таблицах имют одинаковые значения и размерность то можно использовать EXCEPT

```
select ShortWord from ShortWords where ShortWord like 'arg1' 
EXCEPT
select WORDCOLLECT from CollectWords where WORDCOLLECT like 'arg1';
```

т.е. из первой выборки будут исключены значения второй выборки

Answer (score 0):

Проще всего получить нужные данные объединением запросов

```
select ShortWord from ShortWords where ShortWord like 'arg1' 
union
select WORDCOLLECT from CollectWords where WORDCOLLECT like 'arg1'
```

union оставит по одному слову, если будут совпадающие в двух подзапросах.